# How to change speech pronunciation -- conditional SSML?

Tags: bixby

I have the following view code

```
template ("Here's an AltBrain by #{value(this.author)} on #{value(this.name)}") {speech ("Here's an AltBrain by #{value(this.author)} on #{value(this.name)}")}
```

When it encounters value(this.author) = "GitLab" it butchers the pronunciation to "Gitlib."  How can I correct this?

I see that I could use SSML's speak and sub commands like this

```
<speak> ... <sub alias = \"Git Lab\"> ... but how do I do this dynamically where I want it to adjust this.name if and only if it is a term that has a different pronunciation?
```

Note that as I continue to explore this I realize that there is a fundamental problem which is that everywhere Bixby encounters "GitLab" she is going to mispronounce it. We need a mechanism for a global change in that, like a dialog file. Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it sounds like a TTS bug that require fix from the Bixby Platform. I will file a ticket for that.

However there are cases where developers may want display and speech be different. One trick is to use the value dialog. When in display, use raw, and when in speech, use value.

Here is the value dialog:

```
dialog (Value) {
  match: TextSource (this)
  if (this == 'GitLab') {
    template("Git Lab")
  }
  else {
    template("#{raw(this)}")
  }
}
```

Here is how to take advantage of the value dialog.

```
  message {
    template ("From #{raw(action.question.source)}, #{value(action.question.textQuestion)}") {
      speech ("From #{value(action.question.source)}, #{value(action.question.textQuestion)}")
    }
  }
```

For the complete capsule to test, [download it from Github](https://github.com/MinChengVivLabs/example.voiceInput). I've made the capsule for other purpose, but try the the utterance "try one question" and see the input-view.

Answer (score 0):

This is a hideous hack, and provides only a partial solution.

```
  if (exists(this.author) && this.author == 'GitLab')
       { template ("Here's an AltBrain by **GitLab** on #{value(this.name)}")
 {speech ("Here's a AltBrain by **Git Lab** on #{value(this.name)}")}}

   else ...
```